# Unable to create a filter on an existing lookup field

Tags: administration, lookup-filter

Wondering whether anyone has run into this before.  I have a lookup field on one of my custom objects to the Contract object and want to add a lookup filter to that field.  According to https://emea.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_filtered_lookups_cheatsheet.pdf this should be a breeze, just click Edit for that field and go to the Lookup Filter Options.  But when I click Edit, there is no section with that name on the edit screen.  Is there any gotcha for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aahh, ran into a limitation of lookup fields, according to https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&language=en_US Contracts are not a part of the Standard Object list that can have Lookup Filters applied.

Just wanted to get that out there if anyone else runs into the same problem :)

Comment: mark you answer as "solved" :)

Comment: I do that my marking it as the correct answer, right?  I'll be able to do that tomorrow.